# Why is this replace function not working for the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, node-webkit

I have a filename i split in parts but for some reason there is one string in which I cannot replace one character

```
var filename = "first part - 5-10 - third part.txt"
var filenameparts = filename.split(" - ");
console.log(filenameparts);
console.log(filenameparts[0].substring(filenameparts[0].indexOf(' '))); //this prints fine

Array[3]
  0: "first part"
  1: "5-10"
  2: "third part.txt"
  length: 3
part
```

When I add this line nothing prints to console and in the html appears:

```
console.log(filenameparts[1].replace("-","/"));
```

HTML:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Comment: There is no match for `" - "` so you end up with an array with only one part, and that is why `filenameparts[1]` is undefined.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vsc3dum9/

Comment: What? No, console.log(filenameparts); is printing an array with 3 strings. I need to split the second string in position 1. I added more info, I think there is something wrong with node-webkit.

Comment: Well, Node is telling you that `filenameparts[1]` is `undefined`, there's really no question about that !

Comment: @shuji are you sure you're getting a correct array?

Comment: Yes, the error only prints when I add the replace line, but it's correctly printing the array before that.

Comment: @shuji: That's impossible, so you need to look more closely. The `replace` line isn't the problem, it's a symptom of a problem. The problem is that `filenameparts` doesn't have an entry at index 1, and so clearly is not the array you're seeing output. E.g., your observations are tricking you (it happens to us all).

Comment: I ran this code exactly and it works for me.  The result of the replace is `5/10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in  your question simply will not cause the error you've described (see below), so you need to look elsewhere. Note that if `filename` **doesn't** have at least one `" - "` in it (it does in your question, but presumably you're actually getting that name from somewhere rather than using a literal string), you'll get back an array with only one entry from `split`, and so you really do need to have a guard on your `filenameparts[1]` line, e.g.:

```
if (filenameparts.length > 1) {
    console.log(filenameparts[1].replace("-","/")); 
}
```

Proof that your code in the question works:

```js
var filename = "first part - 5-10 - third part.txt"
var filenameparts = filename.split(" - ");
snippet.log(filenameparts);
snippet.log(filenameparts[0].substring(filenameparts[0].indexOf(' '))); //this prints fine
snippet.log(filenameparts[1].replace("-","/"));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

*This is a Community Wiki because it's really a comment with a Stack Snippet in it.*

Comment: Thank you so much man, you are right. I was listing files recursively so the directory names were also evaluating.